# How do I delete old calendar items in Outlook 2003?

Tags: calendar, microsoft-outlook-2003

I'm trying to delete old calendar items (I have a few years' worth) in Outlook and was wondering if there was a way to delete only non-recurring items as I need the recurring events for the future.

I tried View > Arrange by > Current view > Category and figured that I could manually check and delete any calendar items by hand.  Is there a more efficient way to do this without having to actually script code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Category view is correct. If it isn't showing, you'll want to add the "Advanced" toolbar (rt. click on a toolbar and choose "Advanced").

On the Advanced Toolbar, click the "Group By Box" button.

Rt. Click on any column header. Select "Field Chooser"

Drag the "Recurrence" field above the column headers into the Group by Box. This will allow you to see which appointments have no recurrence.

An appt. can be selected by clicking the calendar icon at the left of the appointment. Select the first one you want to delete, then hold Shift, then select the last one you want to delete. Then hit your delete key.

I have found that if you select too many, it can be a very slow process. I believe that is due to the server. Still, you can select dozens at a time and get through the list pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried an advanced find against your calendar with an appointment field filter of `Recurrence equals (none)` ?